# Jenkins and github commit statuses

Tags: jenkins, github

I am having issues getting GitHub to talk to Jenkins after an upgrade to our private GitHub.

I had the webhooks setup and everything was working till the upgrade now I am getting the following error in the logs

> ERROR: [GitHub Commit Status Setter] Failed to update commit state on
>   GitHub. Ignoring exception [{"message":"Not
>   Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.11/v3"}]

has anyone seen this issue before?

Added Job:

[image]

Added error log:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: <redacted URL>
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:612)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:594)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:272)
Caused: org.kohsuke.github.GHFileNotFoundException: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.11/v3"}
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.handleApiError(Requester.java:686)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:293)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:234)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.createCommitStatus(GHRepository.java:1075)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.status.GitHubCommitStatusSetter.perform(GitHubCommitStatusSetter.java:160)
Caused: org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.common.CombineErrorHandler$ErrorHandlingException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.common.CombineErrorHandler.handle(CombineErrorHandler.java:74)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.status.GitHubCommitStatusSetter.perform(GitHubCommitStatusSetter.java:164)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Comment: are you using PIPELINE or regular jobs ?

Comment: Hi this is a regular job

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of the job ?

Comment: As you can imagine this contains quite a bit of sensitive stuff, so I can't do that, is there something in particular you are looking for ?

Comment: I want to see to git section , are you clone 1 repo or more ? , and I want to see the setter section as well

Comment: Image added to the question, and to add most of the git urls are using a token to get information rather then credentials

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update the status result

[image]

Comment: ok, but why does setting the pending step fail ? I have also had it that way with the same result above.

Comment: the pending failed as well ? can you upload the log ?
maybe you don't have permissions to update the git status ?

Comment: I have added the full exception, but to me it would seem that the original line above seems to be the key piece of information.

[{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.11/v3"}]

also I am sure that the token used has permissions.

Comment: try to remove the pending message , let's see if it works without it

Comment: Nope, it does not, I get two errors one for the pending, but jenkins ignores it and carries on then the rest of the scripts run and fail(expected) then the github set fails and the whole job fails.

Comment: I see that you don't need credentials to clone the code  , try to use a user with write permissons

Comment: we use tokens due to 2fa, and I have used a token that has full permissions to no effect, one thing to note is that this was working before a Github enterprise upgrade to 2.11. 

Also the message does not seem to be auth related, but I have tried to rule that out by setting the statuses manually with postman but I have not been able to work out how to achieve that yet

Comment: Sorry , don't have any other idea ... , if it works before maybe your github team can help you with that ...